# SMB auto mount doesn't work after upgrading to ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, mount, smb

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04, the automount doesn't work anymore.

Because I connect to a FreeNAS-11.2-U2.1 server, SMB 1.0 supported was dropped but later added back.  I have set a check box to reactive that smb feature.

This is the script I had before:

```
//192.168.1.5/Media /mnt/smb cifs vers=1.0,noauto,guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

What am I missing that is may be caused by the upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `noauto` option enabled, meaning that you don't want it to be mounted automatically.
Remove that option:

```
//192.168.1.5/Media /mnt/smb cifs vers=1.0,guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

Comment: I should of realized it.  It was 11pm so I didn't see it.  THANK YOU for your assistance!